# VSTS 2010 : can use VSTS 2010 for two different users?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have single server with VSTS 2010.
can we install one VSTS and use with two different users in the same time ?

what is happen is this :
 User_B can open projects from User_A but it time he need to change something
 jump windows and asked to save the project..(*.sln file)

Comment: Please try to clarify your question, especially the second paragraph is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are doing is probably a license violation.

Also, this is really not the best way to go about multi-user software development. If you have more than 1 developer working on the same project - you need some form of Source Control. There are plenty of best-of-breed free/open-source version control systems (subversion, git, mercurial, to name a few) you can use.

Developers should each develop on their own machine, and then check-in changes to a source control system.